# Aruino UNO not getting programmed on MAC OSX

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ch340

I am using MAC OSX Mojave and trying to program an Arduino UNO board. However, whenever I start the Arduino IDE, I only find one port in the ports section called: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port. 
When I select that, since there is no other option, I get the following error code on pressing 'Upload' button. The error code I receive is given in image. [image: error msg on pressing upload]

My programmer is ArduinoISP and the board is Arduino UNO 
[image: image of options in tools menu]

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Note
I have reinstalled CH34x drivers (latest version v.5)

Comment: It is either a driver, cable, or physical USB port issue - "/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port" is not an Arduino. Have you tried moving the Arduino and cable to another computer (just to see if it is even recognized)? Substituting another cable?

Comment: Mojave is known to be a complete pig. Read this: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=570440.0

Comment: Your newly installed driver might be quarantined by Mac security, Click on System Preferences -> Security & Privacy to see if it is blocked.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks a lot! The first suggestion on the forum that deals with removing the serial files and rebooting worked! Finally, I can actually use my Arduino. Thank you.